# What is the difference between `Ctrl + C` and `kill -2` command sending a signal using?

Tags: bash, signals

For example, while I am running the script below, if I send an **INT** signal with **Ctrl + C**, the script file gets interrupted immediately. But when I try the same process with the kill command as `kill -2 pid`, the `sleep` command is expected to finish for the interrupt signal to be valid. What exactly is the reason for this situation?

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo signal received!!' SIGINT

echo "The script pid is $$"
sleep 30
```

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor You are right, i fixed now.

Comment: What happens if you send `sigint` to the script and to `sleep`?  (**My guess** is that this is what ctrl-c is doing).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I would like to thank you for taking your precious time and returning to the questions I asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that when you press `Ctrl-C` the *kernel* will send a `SIGINT` signal to both your script and the `sleep` command (i.e. it will send the signal to the whole *process group*), but with `kill -INT $pid` you're only signaling `$pid` (supposedly your script).

Assuming that your script is started from a typical interactive shell (i.e. the script is the process group leader), just negating the pid should work: `kill -INT -$pid`.